# Bootstrap Modal opens even if there is a validation error

Tags: html, bootstrap-modal, bootstrap-5

I created a sign up page with HTML and Bootstrap 5. I made a Validation for this page with the help of Bootstrap. When the registration is complete, a Modal appears. However, there is a problem. Modal opens even if there is an empty space in the form section, that is, even if there is a Validation error. How can I prevent this?

I wrote a code like this:

```js
(function() {
  'use strict'

  // Fetch all the forms we want to apply custom Bootstrap validation styles to
  var forms = document.querySelectorAll('.needs-validation')

  // Loop over them and prevent submission
  Array.prototype.slice.call(forms)
    .forEach(function(form) {
      form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
        if (!form.checkValidity()) {
          event.preventDefault()
          event.stopPropagation()
        }

        form.classList.add('was-validated')
      }, false)
    })
})()
```

```css
body {
  background-color: rgb(232, 232, 232);
}

.box {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 45%;
  height: 600px;
  background-color: rgb(204, 204, 204);
  border-radius: 30px;
  padding-top: 25px;
  padding-left: 40px;
  padding-right: 40px;
}

.box>.title {
  font-size: 38px;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-align: center;
}

.box>.label {
  text-align: center;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 950px) {
  .box {
    width: 85%;
  }
  .box>.title {
    font-size: 25px;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .box>.label {
    font-size: 16px;
    text-align: center;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-GLhlTQ8iRABdZLl6O3oVMWSktQOp6b7In1Zl3/Jr59b6EGGoI1aFkw7cmDA6j6gD" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-w76AqPfDkMBDXo30jS1Sgez6pr3x5MlQ1ZAGC+nuZB+EYdgRZgiwxhTBTkF7CXvN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div style="height: 80px;"></div>
  <div class="box">
    <div class="title">Kayıt Ol</div>
    <div class="label">Kayıt olmak için lütfen aşağıya bilgilerinizi giriniz. Bilgileriniz çalınmayacaktır.</div>
    <form class="row needs-validation" novalidate>
      <div style="height: 15px;"></div>
      <label for="nameValidation" class="form-label">Ad:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nameValidation" required>
      <div class="valid-feedback">
        Looks good!
      </div>
      <label for="surnameValidation" class="form-label">Soyad:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="surnameValidation" required>
      <div class="valid-feedback">
        Looks good!
      </div>
      <label for="emailValidation" class="form-label">First name</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="emailValidation" required>
      <div class="valid-feedback">
        Looks good!
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
          <div class="form-check">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="invalidCheck" required>
            <label class="form-check-label" for="invalidCheck">
                            Agree to terms and conditions
                        </label>
            <div class="invalid-feedback">
              You must agree before submitting.
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal">
                        Launch demo modal
                    </button>

        </div>
        <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
          <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
                <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-body">
                ...
              </div>
              <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Thanks for help.

I couldn't think of a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Catch the show.bs.modal and test the validity again

Alternatively count if the number of `.was-validated` equals number of forms on the page

```js
(function() {
  'use strict'

  // Fetch all the forms we want to apply custom Bootstrap validation styles to
  var forms = document.querySelectorAll('.needs-validation');

  // Loop over them and prevent submission
  [...forms]
  .forEach(function(form) {
    form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
      if (!form.checkValidity()) {
        event.preventDefault()
        event.stopPropagation()
      }
      form.classList.add('was-validated')
    }, false)
  })

  document.getElementById('exampleModal').addEventListener('show.bs.modal', function(e) {
    const errors = [...forms].some(form => !form.checkValidity());
    if (errors) e.preventDefault();
  });
})()
```

```css
body {
  background-color: rgb(232, 232, 232);
}

.box {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 45%;
  height: 600px;
  background-color: rgb(204, 204, 204);
  border-radius: 30px;
  padding-top: 25px;
  padding-left: 40px;
  padding-right: 40px;
}

.box>.title {
  font-size: 38px;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-align: center;
}

.box>.label {
  text-align: center;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 950px) {
  .box {
    width: 85%;
  }
  .box>.title {
    font-size: 25px;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .box>.label {
    font-size: 16px;
    text-align: center;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-GLhlTQ8iRABdZLl6O3oVMWSktQOp6b7In1Zl3/Jr59b6EGGoI1aFkw7cmDA6j6gD" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-w76AqPfDkMBDXo30jS1Sgez6pr3x5MlQ1ZAGC+nuZB+EYdgRZgiwxhTBTkF7CXvN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div style="height: 80px;"></div>
  <div class="box">
    <div class="title">Kayıt Ol</div>
    <div class="label">Kayıt olmak için lütfen aşağıya bilgilerinizi giriniz. Bilgileriniz çalınmayacaktır.</div>
    <form class="row needs-validation" novalidate>
      <div style="height: 15px;"></div>
      <label for="nameValidation" class="form-label">Ad:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nameValidation" required>
      <div class="valid-feedback">
        Looks good!
      </div>
      <label for="surnameValidation" class="form-label">Soyad:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="surnameValidation" required>
      <div class="valid-feedback">
        Looks good!
      </div>
      <label for="emailValidation" class="form-label">First name</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="emailValidation" required>
      <div class="valid-feedback">
        Looks good!
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
          <div class="form-check">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="invalidCheck" required>
            <label class="form-check-label" for="invalidCheck">
                            Agree to terms and conditions
                        </label>
            <div class="invalid-feedback">
              You must agree before submitting.
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal">
                        Launch demo modal
                    </button>

        </div>
        <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
          <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
                <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-body">
                ...
              </div>
              <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Here is a version with only one form

```js
(function() {
  'use strict'
  const form = document.querySelector('.needs-validation');
  form.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
    const thisForm = e.target;
    if (!thisForm.checkValidity()) {
      event.preventDefault()
      event.stopPropagation()
    }
    thisForm.classList.add('was-validated')
  });
  document.getElementById('exampleModal').addEventListener('show.bs.modal', (e) => {
    if (!form.checkValidity()) e.preventDefault();
  });
})()
```

```css
body {
  background-color: rgb(232, 232, 232);
}

.box {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 45%;
  height: 600px;
  background-color: rgb(204, 204, 204);
  border-radius: 30px;
  padding-top: 25px;
  padding-left: 40px;
  padding-right: 40px;
}

.box>.title {
  font-size: 38px;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-align: center;
}

.box>.label {
  text-align: center;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 950px) {
  .box {
    width: 85%;
  }
  .box>.title {
    font-size: 25px;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .box>.label {
    font-size: 16px;
    text-align: center;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-GLhlTQ8iRABdZLl6O3oVMWSktQOp6b7In1Zl3/Jr59b6EGGoI1aFkw7cmDA6j6gD" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-w76AqPfDkMBDXo30jS1Sgez6pr3x5MlQ1ZAGC+nuZB+EYdgRZgiwxhTBTkF7CXvN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div style="height: 80px;"></div>
  <div class="box">
    <div class="title">Kayıt Ol</div>
    <div class="label">Kayıt olmak için lütfen aşağıya bilgilerinizi giriniz. Bilgileriniz çalınmayacaktır.</div>
    <form class="row needs-validation" novalidate>
      <div style="height: 15px;"></div>
      <label for="nameValidation" class="form-label">Ad:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nameValidation" required>
      <div class="valid-feedback">
        Looks good!
      </div>
      <label for="surnameValidation" class="form-label">Soyad:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="surnameValidation" required>
      <div class="valid-feedback">
        Looks good!
      </div>
      <label for="emailValidation" class="form-label">First name</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="emailValidation" required>
      <div class="valid-feedback">
        Looks good!
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
          <div class="form-check">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="invalidCheck" required>
            <label class="form-check-label" for="invalidCheck">
                            Agree to terms and conditions
                        </label>
            <div class="invalid-feedback">
              You must agree before submitting.
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal">
                        Launch demo modal
                    </button>

        </div>
        <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
          <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
                <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-body">
                ...
              </div>
              <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hello. When I left the inputs blank, there was a red border and a warning appeared just below it. It's not coming out now.

Comment: That was also not the case in the original code YOU posted